# DataSet showing name only and not table data c#

Tags: c#

In my c# code I am trying to create an excel report with my data. I was trying some way to give my data headers. So I called my stored procedure added my dataset tables and now I want to add one of those tables to be a row in my data table. It returns one row my dataset does. example of how I want it to look:

```
Title
93.76%  00:23:59    00:33:41    95.56%  00:57:40    94.66%
```

Seems simple enough that's why I choose datatable to do so with and not dataset because I was limited to the dataset tables formatting. How can I get my data table to display the the data and not the name? Code provided below. I am also up for any other suggestions on how to accomplish this. If you need any more info or code please feel free to ask.

```
var dt = new DataTable("IncomingProductReport");
dt.Columns.Add("A Line Down Time");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("L_GetTimeTotals", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@startTime", SqlDbType.DateTime, 30).Value = RadDateTimePicker2.SelectedDate;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@endTime", SqlDbType.DateTime, 30).Value = RadDateTimePicker3.SelectedDate;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

var ds = new DataSet();

ds.Tables.Add("IncomingProductTotals");
ds.Tables.Add("IncomingProductTotalsA");
ds.Tables.Add("IncomingProductTotalsB");
ds.Tables.Add("IncomingProductTotals1");
ds.Tables.Add("IncomingProductTotalsA1");
ds.Tables.Add("IncomingProductTotalsB1");

da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "IncomingProductTotals");
da.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "IncomingProductTotalsA");
da.TableMappings.Add("Table2", "IncomingProductTotalsB");
da.TableMappings.Add("Table3", "IncomingProductTotals1");
da.TableMappings.Add("Table4", "IncomingProductTotalsA1");
da.TableMappings.Add("Table5", "IncomingProductTotalsB1");

da.Fill(ds);

ds.Tables.Remove("IncomingProductTotalsA");
ds.Tables.Remove("IncomingProductTotalsB");
ds.Tables.Remove("IncomingProductTotalsA1");
ds.Tables.Remove("IncomingProductTotalsB1");

dt.Rows.Add("Line 1 Totals");
dt.Rows.Add(ds.Tables["IncomingProductTotals"]);
dt.Rows.Add("Line 2 Totals");
dt.Rows.Add(ds.Tables["IncomingProductTotals1"]);

ExcelHelper.ToExcel(dt, "DownTimeTotals.xls", Page.Response);
```

Comment: u sure table has data?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad yes checked db

Comment: @EhsanSajjad should look like this 93.76% 00:23:59 00:33:41 95.56% 00:57:40 94.66%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> dt.Columns.Add("A Line Down Time");

You are adding a Column to the DataTable. You do not say what type so it will be the default type and that is string.

> ```
> dt.Rows.Add(ds.Tables["IncomingProductTotals"]);
> ```

Then you try to put a complete DataTable into a cell of a Column that expects strings. To get a string from the given object the system will call the ToString method of the DataTable. And ToString is implemented as returning the Tablename of a DataTable.

You need to take the data in the DataTables to put into the dt DataTable not the DataTables itself. That makes no sense. Allowed types for a column if you really wanted to put a DataTable into a DataTable are only the once described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).